# How to disable the CListCtrl select option

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I don't know how to disable the `CListCtrl` select option. I want to override the `CListCtrl` class method or handle any window command ? Thanks.

Comment: [CListCtrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78(v=vs.100).aspx) is a class used for managing a Windows Common Controls ListView control. Like all Windows Common Controls, you will likely have to provide a notification handler to perform whatever action, or lack thereof, that you want (or don't want) done. Get a book on MFC or maybe [try this](http://bit.ly/10A1ihY).

Answer (score 8):

If you want to stop the user selecting an item in a `CListCtrl`, you need to derive your own class from `CListCtrl` and add a message handler for the `LVN_ITEMCHANGING` notification.

So, an example class `CMyListCtrl` would have a header file:

MyListCtrl.h

```
#pragma once

class CMyListCtrl : public CListCtrl
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CMyListCtrl)

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

public:
    // LVN_ITEMCHANGING notification handler
    afx_msg void OnLvnItemchanging(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult);
};
```

And then MyListCtrl.cpp:

```
#include "MyListCtrl.h"

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CMyListCtrl, CListCtrl)

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyListCtrl, CListCtrl)
    ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(LVN_ITEMCHANGING, &CMyListCtrl::OnLvnItemchanging)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMyListCtrl::OnLvnItemchanging(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    // LVN_ITEMCHANGING notification handler
    LPNMLISTVIEW pNMLV = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLISTVIEW>(pNMHDR);

    // is the user selecting an item?
    if ((pNMLV->uChanged & LVIF_STATE) && (pNMLV->uNewState & LVNI_SELECTED))
    {
        // yes - never allow a selected item
        *pResult = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // no - allow any other change
        *pResult = 0;
    }
}
```

So you can, for example, add a normal `CListCtrl` to a dialog, then create a member variable for it (by default it will be `CListCtrl`) then edit your dialog's header file to `#include "MyListCtrl.h` and change the list control member variable from `CListCtrl` to `CMyListCtrl`.

Comment: I tried it but it is Invalid now.