# How to specifically prevent or lock a Row selection in a List Control (Report View)

Tags: mfc, row, listcontrol

Good day,

My purpose of creating List_Control Report view is to generate a list of data and ofcourse user is allowed to select which data they want. And so my problem is the first item which displayed should be a reference(or)read only purpose. Which means i do not want user to select it. I've searched online around, with my few months of programming background which was really toughed to understand. I used below's method to generate my list of data.

```
    lvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
    lvItem.iItem = cnt;
    lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
    lvItem.pszText = data1;
    nItem = m_List.InsertItem(&lvItem);
    m_List.SetItemText(nItem, 1, data2);
    m_List.SetItemText(nItem, 2, data3);
    m_List.SetItemText(nItem, 3, data4);
    m_List.SetItemText(nItem, 4, data5);
    m_List.SetExtendedStyle(m_List.GetExtendedStyle()
    |LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);
```

With my childish thought i hope there's a function which i could just add on like "lvitem.ROWSELECTLock = TRUE" but ofcourse this MFC do not provide it.

*Side topic abit, any recommendation of MFC book for a starter like me?

Thank you in advance for your reply.

/Kevin

Comment: there is a way to "block" the selection, but, is that really what you need? If you don't want the user to select it, should that item be in the list box at all? shouldn't that information be in some other place, like in a label or in the header?

Comment: Yes i understood where's your point of view coming from. If i couldn't find a way to block user from clicking on it. Ill just place at another place as you mentioned. My purpose to keep them together is because they share the same column information which i generated from LVCOLUMN. Sorry for my bad explanation i hope you get the picture.

Comment: I understood. but still then I really think you should put that information in a separated area, the user will surely click on it and will ask to himself: "why can't I click on this?", so unless there is another reason, in my opinion, you should remove it from the "main list box" and put it somewhere else.
anyway i'm trying it myself, because it is an interesting exercise =)

Comment: anyway, are you using CListView or a CDialog as the parent of your CListControl?

Comment: Hi @Robson , only one List View on my program so i guess is CListView as my main.

Answer (score 2):

found it!

#### If you want to derive your own class or use CListView

there is already another question on stack overflow where you can gather the information needed to disable the selecting.
[How to disable the CListCtrl select option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581153/how-to-disable-the-clistctrl-select-option)

so to "prevent" the selection just on the first item you just have to add a condition in the "if" checking if the "changing" item is the one you want, in your case the first one (the index starts on 0)

```
if ((pNMLV->uChanged & LVIF_STATE) && (pNMLV->uNewState & LVNI_SELECTED) && pNMLV->iItem == 0)
```

#### If you want to do it inside a dialog without deriving your own class

1. declare the CListCtrl variable in your dialog class
2. add the method declaration to the dialog

   afx_msg void OnItemchangingList(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult);
3. add the entry to your message map

   `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDialog, CDialog)

       ON_NOTIFY(LVN_ITEMCHANGING, IDC_LIST1, &CMyDialog::OnItemchangingList)
   END_MESSAGE_MAP()`
4. add the method to the ".cpp" file of your dialog (it is the same as the ClistView method)

   void CMyDialog::OnItemchangingList(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
   {
       // LVN_ITEMCHANGING notification handler
       LPNMLISTVIEW pNMLV = reinterpret_cast(pNMHDR);

   ```
   // is the user selecting an item?
   if ((pNMLV->uChanged & LVIF_STATE) && (pNMLV->uNewState & LVNI_SELECTED) && pNMLV->iItem == 0)
   {       
       // yes - never allow a selected item
       *pResult = 1;
   }
   else
   {
       // no - allow any other change
       *pResult = 0;
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Yes, i saw this yesterday. It was too difficult to me to understand how to derive it from my own class. But i've decided to give it a try !

Comment: ok, i just found a way to not derive it, i will update the answer

Comment: @KevinYong just read your other comment, for the CListView, as it just encapsulate the CListrCtrl you can use the "ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(LVN_ITEMCHANGING" anyway

Comment: sorry for the late and thanks for the reply. 1. I'm having problem entering the entry to message map. I have to remove the character '&' a pointer i guess or else ill receive error while compiling. 2. The same goes to "LPNMLISTVIEW" pNMLV= reinterpret_Cast(pNMHDR)" kept giving error C2059 : '('    3. how should i utilize this OnItemchangingList function?  As i need to pre fix this item so that user will not able to click on it.

Comment: forgot to tag you @Robson

Comment: OnItemchangingList gets called when the event LVN_ITEMCHANGING is raised. what is the full error message you are getting?